# Setting HttpServletResponse

Tags: http, jakarta-ee, servlets

If I call the setStatus method on an httpservletrequest, but don't actually send a response (using the requestdispatcher, or write out a response with the writer), does the status code actually get sent?

For example, inside of doPost all I did was the following, and nothing else:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);
```

Would that code actually be set on the response returned to the client, or do I actually have to use the requestdispatcher or write out some response?

I'm asking because I'm using a service that requires a 200 response to be returned after they make a doPost request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sent, but if you're worried, do

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_REQUEST_ENTITY_TOO_LARGE);
response.flushBuffer();
```

[Flushing the buffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#flushBuffer()) commits the response.